# Is it possible to define bit column in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-types

Sounds like a basic question but I couldn't seem to find it.
Is there a way to define in `SQLite` a column which will be a single `bit`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### No.

> SQLite does **not have a separate Boolean storage class**. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

[Source](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: I guess it is because, internally sqlite takes only required amount of memory and it is optimized in that way, So, an Integer field holding value 0 or 1 will only take 1 byte.

Comment: They could save space by joining the result of 8 rows boolean values and saving them as a byte... but looks like nobody cared

Answer (score -1):

AS at 2021-01-20, I should say **YES**, you can define bit datatype in SQLite and it's working.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, sqlite contains boolean, but boolean is not true/false, it is any boolean number. OP is asking for a single bit.